# Make error on installing php 5.3 on ubuntu using phpenv

Tags: php, phpfarm

I tried installing PHP 5.3 using phpfarm and phpenv but I keep getting the following error at make.

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: ***
>   [sapi/fpm/php-fpm] Error 1

Comment: Unless you have a *really good reason* for using PHP 5.3, can I suggest using PHP 5.6. The former is no longer supported and the latter might be easier to install.

Comment: @dave I have a legacy app we need to convert to current version of php and I don't want to downgrade my Ubuntu installation hence why I'm trying to side load php 5.3 using php 5.3.

Comment: That sounds like it meets the criteria for a *really good reason* :)